# TikZ's extended line penetrates the figure caption

Tags: tikz-pgf, floats, captions

Here is an example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}\centering

\begin{tikzpicture}[extended line/.style={shorten >=-#1,shorten <=-#1}]
\draw [very thick, extended line=1cm] (0,0) -- (0,1);
\end{tikzpicture}

\caption{This is a test caption.}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

and its outcome:

[image]

How can I move the tikzpicture above the caption?

Comment: I am just curious. What do you use the negative shortening for?

Comment: @hpesoj626 When I know the coordinates of two points, I want to draw a line that passes the two points with some extended lines at the both ends. negative shortening = extending

Comment: The reason is that the `shorten` pair doesn't update the bounding box. So you need to use something that does update it such as Qrrbrbirlbel's answer.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Is this a valid option?

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\tikzset{
    extended line/.style={
        to path={
            ($(\tikztostart)!-#1!(\tikztotarget)$) --  ($(\tikztotarget)!-#1!(\tikztostart)$) \tikztonodes
        }
    }
}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [very thick] (0,0) to[extended line=1cm] (0,1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{This is a test caption.}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `-#1cm` or other units are required to use lengths otherwise it will use fraction of the path length. Ah nevermind you supplied it in the command sorry.

Comment: @percusse Yes and no: Yes, fractions will be used when no unit is given. And no, I wouldn't define the `to path` with `#1cm` because than a) one has to use `extended line=1` (without the unit) and b) only `cm` are possible. I see this even as an advantage over `shorten >`.

Comment: I've updated the comment :)