# Lines with `shorten >` don't count towards image size

Tags: tikz-pgf, boxes, dimensions

I use [the technique mentioned here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/19349/10844) to extend a line through two points: using `shorten >` and `shorten <` with negative values.

However, the part of the lines that is generated by theses `shorten` commands doesn't seem to be taken into account for the size of the whole image. Therefore these parts can overlap with the figure caption or even surrounding text, see image below.
(I indicated the size of the image by `show background image`.)

How can the size of the image be automatically adjusted?

(When typing the question [this similar topic](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/136373/10844) showed up - however, it didn't ask for a solution but just mentioned the problem.)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\tikzset{extended/.style = { red, shorten >=-1cm, shorten <=-1cm } }


\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \begin{tikzpicture}[show background rectangle, background rectangle/.style={fill=lightgray}, tight background]
    \coordinate (A) at (-0.5,0);
    \coordinate (B) at (1.5,-0.2);
    \coordinate (C) at (0.3,1.5);

    \draw[extended] (A) -- (B);
    \draw[extended] (B) -- (C);
    \draw[extended] (C) -- (A);
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \caption{lorem ipsum}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: [Duplicate?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/85295/16595)

Comment: Yes, duplicate... Thanks, @Qrrbrbirlbel! Question can be closed as the solution provided there works.